# What would the new way of passport deserialization look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

In am following a simple MVC tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/building-structuring-node-js-mvc-application/ to build a login authentication system.

Till a few days back, I had a working serialize and deserialize section in my code

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    
    User.findById(id, (error, user) => {
      done(error, user);
    });

  });
```

Recently running the code, I started getting the error `Model.findById() no longer accepts a callback`
Now I understand that the new way would be using write async and await. However, I couldn't find a sample online that guides me towards how to come about writing the code. Could I please be helped here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't so much a Passport question, but a Mongoose question, which now uses promises instead of callbacks.

To convert your code, you can handle the promise using `async/await`, but you still need to call the callback provided by `passport.deserializeUser`:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    return done(null, await User.findById(id));
  } catch(error) {
    return done(error);
  } 
});
```